# How to change the port of websphere/glassfish?

Tags: windows-7, glassfish, websphere

I'm a websphere newbie and would like to change the port number. I read to manual about ports but it didn't say anything about port number 8080 and it says that glassfish is running on 8080. Am I running websphere or glassfish? When I installed websphere a browser started a window saying I'm running glassfish which I thought was another app server. Did I install both?

Comment: You probably have installed Glassfish. Not WebSphere. WebSphere has no basis on Glassfish. WebSphere uses Geronimo.

Comment: Clarification on @ringbearer's comment that "WebSphere uses Geronimo" - only the WAS Community Edition is based on Geronimo; all the other WAS versions use IBM-proprietary containers. [WAS Edition Comparison](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/wasfamily/compare.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server doesn't use Port 8080 by default. If port 8080 indicates that Glassfish is running, then you must have installed and started Glassfish. These are two completely different application servers / products.

The WAS console runs on port 9060 by default, so you may be able to see if you have also started WAS by going to http://localhost:9060/ibm/console. Also, you can check your running processes (via Windows Task Manager, for example) and installed programs (via Windows Programs and Features, or a simple Explorer search) to determine what might be running/installed.

If, after installing/starting WAS, you still want to change your port numbers, you can do this by going to "Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > [appserver] > Ports" (for individual application servers; also these instructions are for WAS 7.0, but should be *similar* if you're using a different version). If you are using WebSphere Application Server ND, there are actually a number of different processes/application servers running at any given time (deployment manager, nodeagents, individual app servers) that open up ports as well. I wouldn't recommend changing any of the default port values unless you are sure that you have a conflict though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change glassfish port on the other hand go to http://localhost:4848 (default port for admin console) and on the menu on the left navigate to:

> Configurations > server-config > Network Config > Network Listeners > http-listener-[1|2]

and there you can change the port.